# Remove focused border from all fabric react elements

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to get rid of the focused border from all the ui controls of fabric react. When I click a button or focus on any fabric element, a blue focused highlight appears as a border on the focused elements.

I have tried to find the style in the styles inspector but none of it represents the focused style.

I want to remove it completely from all the ui elements.

I want to remove this blue border highlight.
[image: This is the blue border I am seeing when I press this icon button.]

This is how I expect the button to look like without focused styles.
[image: This is how the button actually is and I want it to appear the same way.]

Comment: Have you ever tried to set css "outline: none"?

Comment: It did work on one child. But I want on the whole application.

Comment: Hey @PabloDarde it worked. Thanks for the help. I just targeted every HTML element and it worked.

Comment: A word of warning, the focus border is there because it's important for accessibility--users who navigate a website with only the keyboard need to be able to tell where focus currently is. So removing it isn't recommended. See this page for more info. https://www.washington.edu/accessibility/checklist/focus/

Comment: @ecraig12345 then how to improve it as it gives a weird looking feel to users!

Comment: Thinking about it more, this is actually not what the focus border normally looks like in Fabric React (Fabric React's focus border only shows up when using keyboard navigation, and it's black not blue). Can you share more of your code?

Comment: @ecraig12345 it is the latest version of fabric react. What I think is that it is more native to browser instead of fabric!

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @ecraig12345 google chrome

Comment: @JaskaranSingh As already mentioned, you should never disable the focus outline. It's there for accessibility purposes, and your web page will be completely unusable for those who rely on it. It's even hurting sighted users who use keyboard heavily. If you do not like how it looks like on Chrome, you will need add your own styles via CSS. Note that each browser has different styles for the focus outline. Also, this has nothing to do with Office UI Fabric.